# Hyper-V standards, replication before or after exchange

Tags: exchange, hyper-v, domain-controller

I'm currently building my own lab to improve, however I have a couple of general questions.

I have 2 dell R710 servers, with 2012r2 and the hyper-v role installed.

What I want to do is build up 4 VMs, DC1,DC2,Exchange and Sharepoint.

However I wonder what is better, should I build up one server up first completely and once that is finished set up replication to the second hyper-v?

Thank you for reading!

-Thedok

Comment: Create a Hyper-V Failover Cluster with the two Hyper-V host servers.

Comment: Should I set that up before or after I set up my exchange server?
Thanks a lot for your answer, I am not sure if we ever set up hyper-v failover, so this would be awesome to do.

Comment: `1.` Create your Domain Controllers. `2.` Create your Domain. `3.` Join your Hyper-V hosts to the Domain. `4.` Create your Hyper-V Failover cluster. `5.` Create your Exchange server(s). `6.` Cluster your roles (the virtual machines).

Answer (score 3):

Bring in some virtual shared storage and build a Hyper-V cluster. DCs have own replication built-in, and while you can fake HA with Hyper-V Replica for ordinary VMs it's not supported with Exchange and has issues with SharePoint.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2013/07/29/exchange-and-hyper-v-replica-support/

Comment: This. Software defined shared storage is an optimal solution for HA. I have tried Starwind VSAN myself in almost similar environment, no issues so far: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking specifically about Hyper-V Replica then I think it might make sense to balance the load rather than have one host mostly idle.

Set up a DC on each host, and then set up Exchange on one and SharePoint on the other. After this, set up your VM replication and you should be set.

As already mentioned, you don't need to replicate your domain controllers but you do need to be aware of the issues of virtualising ADDS: http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=13171

EDIT:
Since others have suggested failover clustering, I thought I would expand on my answer. Also - as @BaronSamedi1958 pointed out - Exchange and Sharepoint are not supported under replica.

*If* you have the option to use shared (SAN/NAS with SMBv3 support) thorn this would be absolutely the ideal solution. You won't achieve a sensible failover cluster without.

Replica is completely different. It's a DR option as opposed to high availability. It's also not application aware, it just uses snapshots to replicate to another place with a given frequency. **It's not a backup replacement.**

For database solutions with non-shared storage, use SQL Always-on; it's available from 2012. So this would cover SharePoint. I can't speak for Exchange.

In any case, a replica is better than nothing.

Comment: Exchange isn't supported with Hyper-V replica.

Comment: That's not ideal!

Comment: Well "not ideal" = "DOES NOT WORK" in this context. SharePoint isn't much different.